# Error using test command in if statement

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to create an if statement using the test command that checks if the variable "name" contains "Scott Pearce".

```
#!/bin/bash

name="Scott Pearce"
if test $name == "Scott Pearce";
then
      echo "Yes"
else
      echo "No"
fi
```

When I run the script I get an error saying :

```
./script1: line 5: test: too many arguments
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if test "$name" = "Scott Pearce";
```

You need to quote the variable, otherwise when the shell expands it, `test` will not get the right number of arguments since your variable contains a space.

Also the string equality operator for test is `=`, not `==`.

Answer (score 4):

If you really want to test `contains`, then pick one of

bash

```
if [[ $name == *"Scott Pearce"* ]]; then ...
```

POSIX

```
case "$name" in
    *"Scott Pearce"*) echo Hi Scott ;;
    *) echo Begone stranger ;;
esac
```

The `==` operator in bash's `[[` command is a *pattern matching* operator.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Glenn. I wanted to use test just to learn the use of the command.